npm hangs and loglevel verbose is not helping as to why - how to get better logs?
I have the command running (npm version 10.8.2):
npm install --loglevel verbose

and the last few lines are:
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/svgo 298ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@svgr%2fplugin-svgo 262ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@svgr%2fwebpack 240ms (cache revalidated)

Since this has timing info, it must be logged after, when really, need to see the before to know why it is hanging. What repository is down and can I avoid it with something I have locally? How to turn on logs for what is downloading before it downloads the thing so I know what it hung on?
Also, how to set up a timeout as it sat there for 5 minutes with just spinning still.
Twice now, seemed to stop after getting Webpack but I have no idea what it is hung downloading next after that.
